# click an ajax button with cURL php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

i hope you guys help me
i read several similar questions but unfortunately none of them answered me.

i **scraped** a page with a curl.  There is a button inside that page that i want to use.  But that button uses ajax and when i click on it, it has no reaction.  i know that only one file is loaded through curl and its contents, such as css and js, are not loaded.

this is my code

```
    $url = "https://example.com/home";
$ch = curl_init(); 
$ua ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0";
$sessid ="k7r3svjsugahfcm85teoc6hd74";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $sessid); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 echo $data;
```

and the button which i want to use

```
<button type="button" onclick="withdraw();" class="btn btn-info button-confirm">Confirm</button>
```

its function is written in another js file

is there a way i can use that button?

it does not matter if i use curl or other method.
i just wanna do it

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Surely the access to the AJAX script would be protected and wouldn't allow whatever action is tied to it to take place from any source, even if you got your hands on the JS code.

Comment: It's not really clear what overall experience you're trying to achieve.  You could reverse-engineer the AJAX calls and perform those with CURL, you could use a "headless browser" library to interact with the page (including JavaScript) in code, you could make available the other page assets (JS, CSS, etc.) to your output by adding operations to fetch those when requested, or perhaps something else entirely.  It all depends on what your actual goal is.

Comment: FYI 'Scrapped' means to have thrown away. I think you mean __scraped__

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to trigger the click event on that button on a external page.

You can't to that with cURL, because that's just for reading.

If you want to do something on the website and load the JavaScript, you need to open the website with a browser and execute the action inside of that browser.

Maybe you should take a look at this:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

In the features it says "Automate form submission, UI testing, keyboard input, etc.", I think that's what you want.